# zsh-highlighting return strange output on macosx

Tags: syntax-highlighting, zsh, zshrc

I'm using zsh version 5.2 on macosx 10.11.6

When adding

```
source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

as my last line of my .zshrc, everything work well in linux.

On macosx, when starting the terminal and for every command, I got the following output:

```
_zsh_highlight:13: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:14: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:18: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:21: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:24: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:25: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:27: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:28: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:29: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:32: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:32: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:35: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:36: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:39: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:39: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:43: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight_highlighter_main_predicate:3: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight_highlighter_main_predicate
_zsh_highlight_buffer_modified:2: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight_buffer_modified
_zsh_highlight:62: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
(eval):1: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:69: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:69: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:71: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:87: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:90: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:93: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:96: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:100: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
_zsh_highlight:101: scalar parameter ZSH_DEBUG_CMD created globally in function _zsh_highlight
```

The terminal also act strangely when typing. characters appear on everyline. The only similar bug that I found when googling was  concerning phpbrew which is not installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I just force an update on the repo and the bug is gone.
Problem was not in my environment.